# Create type by mixing class and interface in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

Suppose I have a class:

```
export class A {
  constructor(public readonly prop1: string, public readonly prop2: number) {}
}
```

and interface:

```
export interface I {
  readonly numParam: number;
  readonly strParam: string;
}
```

Is it possible to create the type with a mix of all the props from two? So, the resulting type would be:

```
export type AI_HelpMeHere_Smile {
  readonly prop1: string;
  readonly prop2: number;
  readonly numParam: number;
  readonly strParam: string;
}
```

Comment: You can use either interface extension or type intersections, as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/Wyqv2W).  Does that meet your needs? If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: can this be done with a __class__ and interface/type?

Comment: Does [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/Wyqv2W) not demonstrate what you want?  If not, could explain what you're looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be done via the syntax `Type1 & Type2`. This will produce a type with the combined properties of both types, for example:

```
interface A { a: number; }
interface B { b: string; }

type C = A & B;
// Is equivalent to
interface D extends A, B {}
```

This could be utilized in your case. Another thing you can do, as shown in the example, is for the interface to extend the class and the other interface:

```
interface Second extends A, I {}
```

I prefer the first method, since it's less verbose.

Comment: ok, can I do something like that with a __class__ and interface or type?

Comment: @AlexB yes, you can